# How to create a responsive image map with pure HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am looking to use a picture of a world map with pins on certain places within the map. Once the mouse hovers over these pins, I want them to be clickable so once clicked, they will jump to a certain part of a webpage. I understand how to use area and map tags but I don't know how to go about making it responsive and forcing the area/map tags to stay in one place when the image shrinks down to size for the different screen sizes.

If someone could guide me through this process, that would be great. I am not very familiar with plugins so I am trying to stay away from that if possible.

I have added an example that I have found that similarily represents what I am trying to do.

```css
body {
  font-family: "bookman old style";
}

:target {
  color: lightyellow;
  background: indianred;
}

h3,
h1 {
  color: indianred;
}

img {
  border: 3px dashed indianred;
}

body {
  counter-reset: srl;
}

h3::before {
  counter-increment: srl;
  content: counter(srl)". ";
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center;">The 7 Continents</h1>


<h4 style="text-align:center;">&#10148; Click on the dots in the image to go to a continent section</h4>

<map name="continents_map">
  <area shape="circle" coords="70,70,10" href="#north_america">
  <area shape="circle" coords="133,185,10" href="#south_america">
  <area shape="circle" coords="270,137,10" href="#africa">
  <area shape="circle" coords="292,44,10" href="#europe">
  <area shape="circle" coords="469,201,10" href="#australia">
  <area shape="circle" coords="374,65,10" href="#asia">
  <area shape="circle" coords="340,267,10" href="#antartica">
</map>

<figure style="text-align:center;">
  <img usemap="#continents_map" src= https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/world_continents.png width="600px" />
  <figcaption>World Map</figcaption>
</figure>


<div>
  <h3 id="africa">Africa</h3>
  <p>Africa is the world's second-largest and second-most-populous continent. At about 30.2 million km<sup>2</sup> (11.7 million sq mi) including adjacent islands, it covers six percent of Earth's total surface area and 20.4 percent of its total land area.
    With 1.1 billion people as of 2013, it accounts for about 15% of the world's human population.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="asia">Asia</h3>
  <p>Asia is the Earth's largest and most populous continent, located primarily in the eastern and northern hemispheres. Though it covers only 8.7% of the Earth's total surface area, it comprises 30% of Earth's land area, and has historically been home to
    the bulk of the planet's human population (currently roughly 60%).</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="europe">Europe</h3>
  <p>Europe is the world's second-smallest continent by surface area, covering about 10,180,000 square kilometres (3,930,000 sq mi) or 2% of the Earth's surface and about 6.8% of its land area. Of Europe's approximately 50 countries, Russia is by far the
    largest by both area and population, taking up 40% of the continent (although the country has territory in both Europe and Asia), while Vatican City is the smallest. Europe is the third-most populous continent after Asia and Africa, with a population
    of 739–743 million or about 11% of the world's population. The most commonly used currency is the euro.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="south_america">South America</h3>
  <p>South America has an area of 17,840,000 square kilometers (6,890,000 sq mi). Its population as of 2005 has been estimated at more than 371,090,000. South America ranks fourth in area (after Asia, Africa, and North America) and fifth in population (after
    Asia, Africa, Europe, and North America).</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="north_america">North America</h3>
  <p>North America covers an area of about 24,709,000 square kilometers (9,540,000 square miles), about 4.8% of the planet's surface or about 16.5% of its land area. As of 2013, its population was estimated at nearly 565 million people across 23 independent
    states, representing about 7.5% of the human population. Most of the continent's land area is dominated by Canada, the United States, Greenland, and Mexico, while smaller states exist in the Central American and Caribbean regions. North America is
    the third largest continent by area, following Asia and Africa, and the fourth by population after Asia, Africa, and Europe.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="antartica">Antarctica</h3>
  <p>Antarctica is Earth's southernmost continent, containing the geographic South Pole. It is situated in the Antarctic region of the Southern Hemisphere, almost entirely south of the Antarctic Circle, and is surrounded by the Southern Ocean. At 14.0 million
    km<sup>2</sup> (5.4 million sq mi), it is the fifth-largest continent in area after Asia, Africa, North America, and South America. For comparison, Antarctica is nearly twice the size of Australia. About 98% of Antarctica is covered by ice that averages
    1.9 kilometres (1.2 mi) in thickness, which extends to all but the northernmost reaches of the Antarctic Peninsula.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 id="australia">Australia</h3>
  <p>With a total land area of 8,560,000 square kilometres (3,310,000 sq mi), the Australian continent is the smallest and lowest-lying human-inhabited continent on Earth. The continental shelf connecting the islands, half of which is less than 50 metres
    (160 ft) deep, covers some 2,500,000 square kilometres (970,000 sq mi), including the Sahul Shelf and Bass Strait. As the country of Australia is mostly on a single landmass, and comprises most of the continent, it is sometimes informally referred
    to as an island continent, surrounded by oceans.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this can be done with area ... but you can consider span or div and use position:absolute and consider % with top and left

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And idea is to use tags that you place above the image using absolute position. Then you simply specify % values with top/left.

```css
body {
  font-family: "bookman old style";
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  border: 3px dashed indianred;
  display: block;
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

figure a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2%;
  height: 4%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
}

.north_america {
  top: 22%;
  left: 11.4%;
}

.south_america {
  top: 59.3%;
  left: 21.8%;
}
```

```html
<figure style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="#north_america" class="north_america"></a>
  <a href="#south_america" class="south_america"></a>
  <img usemap="#continents_map" src="https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/world_continents.png" width="300" />
  <figcaption>World Map</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="#north_america" class="north_america"></a>
  <a href="#south_america" class="south_america"></a>
  <img usemap="#continents_map" src="https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/world_continents.png" width="600" />
  <figcaption>World Map</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure style="text-align:center;">
  <a href="#north_america" class="north_america"></a>
  <a href="#south_america" class="south_america"></a>
  <img usemap="#continents_map" src="https://rpsthecoder.github.io/img-repo/world_continents.png" width="1000" />
  <figcaption>World Map</figcaption>
</figure>
```